# Customizing the front end of maximo anywhere apps

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have been working on maximo anywhere apps recently and have a requirement to completely change the look and feel of the work execution app, the oslc layer which talks to maximo in the backend remains the same and all the functionalities are the same but there are some new buttons, notification messages and all sorts of UX aspects to be added to the app, I have just started looking at the architecture and code of the app but does anyone know how can I make changes to the front-end or is it even possible? I could find very few documents available online and all of them spoke of customizing features and functionalities but I coudlnot find any document for adding UX aspects.

It would be great someone could point out any documents or kick-off points which I can start looking into.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for asking, if you're just talking about adding new fields, layouts, screens to the UI, you can do that all through the app.xml, and there are lots of examples on our knowledge center, for example this one:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.2/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.2/config_apps/t_add_rw_fields.html?lang=en

If you're talking about changing the "look" of the existing widgets, this can all be done through css, by overriding our out of the box css classes.  Use Chrome inspector to figure out which css class is being used for each element type, and just override it through standard css approaches.

If you're talking about more advanced customization, for example adding your own new widget types to our screens, it is possible to programmatically instantiate/destroy your own widgets through javascript and add them to our standard application views.  This code is usually hooked on the initialize and back event of our views.  But you'll be responsible for writing the code to synchronize the data layer with your custom widget.  We unfortunately don't have a published example of this customization usecase yet.

We always adding new widget capabilities to our Anywhere UI framework, so I'd love to hear feedback on the new widget types you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Scott, and that does give me a direction to move forward with, we will mostly be looking at the css customizations and here are some of the examples which my client wants : 1. Considering work execution as the base app, (we are developing a solution for a 10inch tablet) so on login we want the screen to be divided into two parts, the left side will contain one pane with some items listed and left pane will contain some more items. 2. if you click any of the tasks in a list, it should pop up a list options, clicking any of the options will take you to the respective screen

Comment: I know how to do these things with simple jquery and javascript and style them using css, however I wasnt sure if i can put them on top of the existing existing work execution code and if they would marry fine. Do you have any pointers on that one?

Comment: Adding a split pane widget to our xml declarative markup is a common requirement in our backlog but we haven't gotten to it yet unfortunately.   I'd recommend using dojox/mobile/FixedSplitter widget simply because we already package the dojo mobile widgets into our application, though you could use an other widget equivalent as well as long as you package them yourselves.  As long as you programmatically place this widget within one of our standard Anywhere <view> elements you should be able to get it to play well with the rest of our UI framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, also right now even my team is in the process of trying out all these UI effects, I will keep updating this post as and when we are able to achieve any of these features. Another point I wanna bring up is we also want to do expandable text - like you click on a line of text and it expands into a small box below it and displays more details...does that sound like something you have implemented earlier or is it something we will have to try on our own?

Comment: Also another point is does maximo anywhere have any front-end implications when the device goes offline or online? The reason I am asking this is the users need some kind of notification on the screen if the device goes offline so if this is not provided we will have to custom create it. So just wanted to confirm. Thanks for all the help again.

Comment: We do show a "server cannot be contacted" notification in 7.5.2. It should show as an icon in the center of the list views.

Comment: thanks scott, we will try that out....thanks a lot for you help till now, its been really useful.

Comment: I had another question regarding the login mechanism followed by anywhere apps - as per my understanding anyone having access to maximo on that particular environment can login into the anywhere apps - is that a correct statement? and if yes then how does it work in a disconnected state? If for any reason maximo is down will it mean that the app will not be able to authenticate a user and hence unable to login as well? And alongwith that is there any other kind of authentication done for example LDAP etc? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: that one might be better as a separate stack overflow question in case other people have the same question, it'll be easier for them to find it, can you post it and tag it maximo-anywhere, I'll see it there..

Comment: Sure, I will put it in a different thread, thankyou so much :)