# Can we customise work execution app from Application Designer?

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

Im new to maximo anywhere, our requirement is to cutomize exiting work execution app. How is that possible? Can we create a new screen as such? Please help.

I have tried to edit crew app through Application Designer but work execution is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not done through App Designer. You can utilize the MobileFirst/Worklight Studio Development environment that is referenced in our documentation. See below:

Customizing Maximo Anywhere mobile apps (Anywhere 7.5.2)
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.2/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.2/config_apps/t_ctr_cust_apps.html

Customizing Maximo Anywhere mobile apps (Anywhere 7.5.1)
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.1/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.1/config_apps/t_ctr_cust_apps.html

See feedback to this similar request below:

[Customizing the front end of maximo anywhere apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457199/customizing-the-front-end-of-maximo-anywhere-apps)

Hope this helps!

M

Comment: I have tried to change label attribute in app.xml however, its not reflecting in app. I have build and run app. Do i miss any configuartion?

Comment: its working for me now, i could see the change after stoping and restarting server